# Prove $\{L(x) \mid x ∈ S\}$ is a linear space if $S$ is a linear space and $L$ is a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

A set S is a linear space if:

- $0 \in S$
- $x \in S$, $y \in S$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, $\beta \in \Bbb R $ then $\alpha x + \beta y \in S$

Given the definition of a Linear transformation $L(\cdot)$

- $L(0) = 0$
- For $x \in S$, $y \in S$, $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, $\beta \in \Bbb R$,  $$L(\alpha x) + L(\beta y) = \alpha L(x) + \beta L(y).$$

Thus, $\{L(x) \mid x \in S\}$ is a linear space.

Is this right? I've never written proofs before so I am at a loss of what to do. I was told this was one of the simpler proofs.

Comment: You want to show that $\{L(x)| x\in S\}$ is a linear space, thus you need to check the condition to be a linear space (which is stated in the first part of your question (for $S$))

Comment: Continuing the previous comment, given $x,y \in S$, you have $Lx,Ly$ in your space; so you need to show that $\alpha Lx+\beta Ly$ is in your space. You've done one step of this; now you should write $L(\alpha x)+L(\beta y)=L(\alpha x + \beta y)$.

Comment: Btw $\Re$ doesn't denote the set of real numbers, but the `real part` of a complex number. You should use $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbf R$ (old style) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is essentially correct, but you need to write a few words when you prove something. Mathematics isn't just writing down formulae, you need to describe what you actually do and what the implications are.

For example, the first part should be written in this way:
Since $S$ is a vector space, there is an element $0 \in S$. By the fundamental properties of linear functions, we have the identity $L(0) = 0$. Therefore $0 \in \{L(x) \mid x \in S\}$.

Try to rewrite the second part on your own.

Comment: IMO It is hard to see if the OP understand what's (s)he's doing, or if the OP is just writing down two definitions....

Comment: To be fair, I didn't know what I was doing. Which is why I asked the question. 

But the answer above shows me what is demanded for in this proof and how i need to elaborate bit more. 

Thank you for the help!